# Add custom post type to query

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, query

```
$saved = $wp_query; query_posts(array('tag__in' => $tag_array, 'showposts' => $args['posts_per_page']));
```

I need this to query standard posts and a custom post type called "property"

I can't seem to get it to show anything from the custom post type when I tried to include another array.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `post_type=`.
Your query would be an array of post types since you want 2 `'post_type' => array( 'post', 'property')`
http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters